# How to iterate over every data entry and subtract each one from another? [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

So i have the following (i'm working with pandas btw.) when i print the head.
As you can see i already get back the first entry of every day.

```
                     first
Timestamp              
2021-03-11  596319.8125
2021-03-12  596349.5625
2021-03-13  602205.1875
2021-03-14  609445.5625
2021-03-15  609479.6250
```

And now i want to get the yield from every day, which means i have to subtract the value (in this case Energy = first) of day 1 from day 2, and than the value of day 2 from day 3 and so on and so forth.

Here's my code so far, i know this only can be a noob problem but i'm very new to programming so i'm thankful for every answer.

```
  import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    
    # set working directory
    os.chdir("Path to CSVs")
    
    # find all csv files in the folder
    # use glob pattern matching -> extension = 'csv'
    # save result in list -> all_filenames
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    # print(all_filenames)
    
    # combine all files in the list
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in all_filenames])
    # Format CSV
    # Transform Timestamp column into datetime
    combined_csv['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_csv.Timestamp)
    # Read out first entry of every day of every month
    combined_csv = combined_csv.resample('D', on='Timestamp')['HtmDht_Energy'].agg(['first'])
    # To get the yield of day i have to subtract day 2 HtmDht_Energy - day 1 HtmDht_Energy
    #
    #
    #
    #
    print(combined_csv.head())
    # export as excel file
    # combined_csv.to_excel('energy_data.xlsx', index=False)
```

After i tried the solution from below with the following code:

```
 import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    
    # set working directory
    os.chdir("C:/Users/winklerm/OneDrive - SOLID Solar Energy Systems GmbH/Desktop/CSVs")
    
    # find all csv files in the folder
    # use glob pattern matching -> extension = 'csv'
    # save result in list -> all_filenames
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    # print(all_filenames)
    
    # combine all files in the list
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in all_filenames])
    # Format CSV
    # Transform Timestamp column into datetime
    combined_csv['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_csv.Timestamp)
    # Read out first entry of every day of every month
    combined_csv = combined_csv.resample('D', on='Timestamp')['HtmDht_Energy'].agg(['first'])
    # To get the yield of day i have to subtract day 2 HtmDht_Energy - day 1 HtmDht_Energy
    combined_csv.assign(tagesertrag=combined_csv["first"]-combined_csv["first"].shift())
    #
    #
    #
    print(combined_csv.head())
    # export as excel file
    # combined_csv.to_excel('energy_data.xlsx', index=False)
```

But my print still looks like this:

```
                  first
Timestamp              
2021-03-11  596319.8125
2021-03-12  596349.5625
2021-03-13  602205.1875
2021-03-14  609445.5625
2021-03-15  609479.6250

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Use `df['yieldc'] = df['first'].diff()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of subtracting `shift()` value

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""" Timestamp                    first
2021-03-11  596319.8125
2021-03-12  596349.5625
2021-03-13  602205.1875
2021-03-14  609445.5625
2021-03-15  609479.6250"""), sep="\s+")

df.assign(yieldc=df["first"]-df["first"].shift())
```

|  | Timestamp | first | yieldc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-03-11 | 596320 | nan |
| 1 | 2021-03-12 | 596350 | 29.75 |
| 2 | 2021-03-13 | 602205 | 5855.62 |
| 3 | 2021-03-14 | 609446 | 7240.38 |
| 4 | 2021-03-15 | 609480 | 34.0625 |

Comment: Thank you very much, i knew it would be simple haha

Comment: And how do i input my whole data into the string io?

Comment: That's just the mechanism I used to paste your sample data into my notebook, you apply same logic to `combined_csv` data frame

Comment: Ok yeah thats what i thought but somehow it didn't add the new column at least i doesnt show it

Comment: `combined_csv["yield"] = combined_csv["first"] - combined_csv["first"].shift()`.  `assign()` returns a dataframe,  so you could also do `combined_csv = combined_csv.assign(yieldc= combined_csv["first"]-combined_csv["first"].shift())`

Comment: And when i additionally want a monthly sum since i have got every month on there? :)

Comment: use what ever part you need of this: `dfs = df.groupby([df.Timestamp.dt.year, df.Timestamp.dt.month]).sum()
dfs.index.set_names(["year","month"], inplace=True)
dfs.reset_index()`.  It's worth doing a bit of study time on understanding pandas